Facing Memory Allocation Issue in malloc During Function Execution
The error stating that memory cannot be allocated at the same point in malloc with the same number of repetitions keeps occurring.
received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
pid_t getPIDByName(const char *processName) {
    char command[256];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "pidof %s", processName);

    FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        return -1;
    }

    pid_t pid;
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &pid) != 1) {
        pclose(fp);     
        return -1;
    }

    pclose(fp);
    return pid;
}

error is in malloc in fscanf on On every 144th execution of the getPIDByName function.
i'll show you my gdb backtrace log
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fa8b80 <main_arena>, 
    bytes=bytes@entry=4096) at malloc.c:3742
#1  0x00007ffff7e56299 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=4096)
    at malloc.c:3066
#2  0x00007ffff7e3dd04 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (
    fp=0x6937700) at filedoalloc.c:101
#3  0x00007ffff7e4ded0 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (
    fp=fp@entry=0x6937700) at libioP.h:948
#4  0x00007ffff7e4cca4 in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x6937700)
    at fileops.c:486
#5  0x00007ffff7e4df86 in __GI__IO_default_uflow (fp=0x6937700)
    at libioP.h:948
#6  0x00007ffff7e20280 in __vfscanf_internal (
    s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, 
    argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffff1620, 
    mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=2) at vfscanf-internal.c:508
#7  0x00007ffff7e1f23d in __isoc99_fscanf (
    stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>)
    at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
#8  0x00007fffccbadca0 in getPIDByName (
    processName=0x7fffcd7cd292 "myaccel")

first, I suspected a memory leak. As I used the valgrind and free, check the memory leak and remain memory.
there are memory leaks, but there are more enough available memory. (50 ~ 55GB)
Additionally, I set the swapmemory to 200GB.
I think this issue was not occured by memory leak.
And then, I tried to determine whether the issue was with malloc or fscanf.
I set the malloc code before {pid_t pid;}. By doing so, the error occured in new line. (malloc code before pid)
is it by process memory limit?
ulimit -v = unlimited
Address Space Exhaustion? -> maybe not, i use the 64bit system
I don't know what's causing the issue, and I have no idea what to try more.

more : my valgrind log (detail part)
cmd : valgrind --tool=memcheck --main-stacksize=1677721600 --track-origins=yes [myprogram]
i write my opinion below valgrind error log
==659566== Invalid write of size 1
==659566==    at 0x48436A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==659566==    by 0x48F235D: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1304)
==659566==    by 0x48E5EE2: fread (iofread.c:38)
==659566==    by 0x1094B5F45: readFromAccel (PARuntime.c:264)
==659566==    by 0x10946DABF: main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x1094B3132: _mlir_ciface_main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x1094B32AE: run_main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x174A151A: onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSessionBase::pyRun(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&) (PyExecutionSessionBase.cpp:153)
==659566==    by 0x17484837: pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}::operator()(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&) const (pybind11.h:110)
==659566==    by 0x1749939E: std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > pybind11::detail::argument_loader<onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&>::call_impl<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&, 0ul, 1ul, pybind11::detail::void_type>(pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&, std::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0ul, 1ul>, pybind11::detail::void_type&&) && (cast.h:1443)
==659566==    by 0x17493044: std::enable_if<!std::is_void<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > >::value, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > >::type pybind11::detail::argument_loader<onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&>::call<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, pybind11::detail::void_type, pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&>(pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&) && (cast.h:1412)
==659566==    by 0x1748BDA9: void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&&, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (*)(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(pybind11::detail::function_call&)#3}::operator()(pybind11::detail::function_call) const (pybind11.h:248)
==659566==  Address 0x128811fff is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==659566== 
==659566== 
==659566== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==659566==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x128811FFF
==659566==    at 0x48436A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==659566==    by 0x48F235D: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1304)
==659566==    by 0x48E5EE2: fread (iofread.c:38)
==659566==    by 0x1094B5F45: readFromAccel (PARuntime.c:264)
==659566==    by 0x10946DABF: main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x1094B3132: _mlir_ciface_main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x1094B32AE: run_main_graph_yolov8n (in /home/hwan/workspace/paper/temp/myexperiments/yolov8n/yolov8n.so)
==659566==    by 0x174A151A: onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSessionBase::pyRun(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&) (PyExecutionSessionBase.cpp:153)
==659566==    by 0x17484837: pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}::operator()(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&) const (pybind11.h:110)
==659566==    by 0x1749939E: std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > pybind11::detail::argument_loader<onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&>::call_impl<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&, 0ul, 1ul, pybind11::detail::void_type>(pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&, std::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0ul, 1ul>, pybind11::detail::void_type&&) && (cast.h:1443)
==659566==    by 0x17493044: std::enable_if<!std::is_void<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > >::value, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > >::type pybind11::detail::argument_loader<onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&>::call<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, pybind11::detail::void_type, pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&>(pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&) && (cast.h:1412)
==659566==    by 0x1748BDA9: void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> >, onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg>(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession::*)(std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&)#1}&&, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > (*)(onnx_mlir::PyExecutionSession*, std::vector<pybind11::array, std::allocator<pybind11::array> > const&), pybind11::name const&, pybind11::is_method const&, pybind11::sibling const&, pybind11::arg const&)::{lambda(pybind11::detail::function_call&)#3}::operator()(pybind11::detail::function_call) const (pybind11.h:248)

in PARuntime.c readFromAccel function is
void readFromAccel(float* data, int size, char* instID, int arg, int chain) {
#if _PRINT_
    printf("readFromAccel!\r\n");
#endif
    printf("<<readFromAccel>> : %s\r\n", instID);
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65);
    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(SharedData), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    SharedData *shared_data = (SharedData*) shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

    c2hLock(shared_data);

    pid_t pid = getPIDByName(ACCEL_PROCESS);

    if (pid == -1) {
        printf("Failed to get PID for process %s\n", ACCEL_PROCESS);
    } else {
        printf("PID of %s: %d\n", ACCEL_PROCESS, pid);
    }

    // c2h file write
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(C2H_FILENAME, "wb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file for writing\r\n");
    }

    unsigned char MD5ID[16];
    computeMD5(instID, MD5ID);

    int datasize = size * sizeof(float);
    unsigned char dummy[12] = {0};

    fwrite(MD5ID, 1, sizeof(MD5ID), file);   // header : MD5 16 byte
    fwrite(&datasize, 1, 4, file);
    fwrite(dummy, 1, sizeof(dummy), file);

    fclose(file);


    c2hSet(shared_data);
    c2hUnLock(shared_data);

    // send interrupt
    shared_data->interrupt_class = SIG_READ;

    if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) == -1) {
        perror("Error sending signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // c2h file read
    while(c2hClearCheck(shared_data) == 0);
    c2hLock(shared_data);

    file = fopen(C2H_FILENAME, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file for reading\r\n");
    }

    unsigned char read_dummy[64];
    printf("readFromAccel >> filepointer0 : %ld\n", ftell(file));
    size_t bytesRead = fread(read_dummy, 1, sizeof(read_dummy), file); // read header
    printf("readFromAccel >> data pointer address: %p, filepointer: %ld, size: %d, datasize: %d, byteread: %zubytes\n",
                             data, ftell(file), size, datasize, bytesRead);
    fread(data, 1, datasize, file);


    printf("c2h file data : ");
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        printf("%f ", *(data + i));
    }
    printf("\r\n");

    fclose(file);

    c2hUnLock(shared_data);
    shmdt(shared_data);

    return;
}

fread(data, 1, datasize, file);

this line is error line.
may be in fread, i accessed wrong memory.. but i allocated by memref in MLIR.
when I confirm the mlir memory is set. like below line (this is my mlir of shared library) %314 is delivered to the readFromAccel funtion.
%alloc = memref.alloc() : memref<1x16x320x320xf32>
%intptr_2 = memref.extract_aligned_pointer_as_index %alloc : memref<1x16x320x320xf32> -> index
%313 = arith.index_cast %intptr_2 : index to i64
%314 = llvm.inttoptr %313 : i64 to !llvm.ptr<f32>

llvm.call @readFromAccel(%314, %c1638400_i32, %315, %c55_i32, %312) : (!llvm.ptr, i32, !llvm.ptr, i32, i32) -> ()
i try to study the reason why data is not allocated

It's more likely you have a buffer overflow somewhere in your program, and it's corrupting the heap used by malloc.

The buffer overflow causes undefined behavior, and the visible results can occur anywhere in the program. valgrind should be able to detect this. Also use -fsanitize=address option when compiling.

Valgrind memcheck reports no other errors apart from leaks?

I didn't explain my environment.. I use the onnx-mlir (LLVM - MLIR refered by onnx) as compiler. so.. I don't use option -fsanitize=address. Additionally, my environment consist of below sequence.
onnx model compiling using onnx-mlir. As a result, make shared library. in python code, import this library. My error occurs in my code adding to onnx-mlir.

Result of valgrind memcheck has many errors. But in my opinion, because there are many extra memory (I confirmed as free command), It is not timing to occur the leak error.

Please edit your question and copy and paste the first error that you get from Valgrind memcheck.

I feel the necessity that change my question. I'll upload question as a new question with more details and more information. Thank you for your response.

I've tried many things, including the methods I told you to find out the cause of the error. As a result, we conclude that MLIR's memref's allocop does not seem to allocate memory properly. I think that's the end of the answer to the question posted here. It helped. Thank you.
